# Regarding Team api integration

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am integrating teams api to schedule meeting,

use this api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings

request

```
    {
"startDateTime":"2019-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
"endDateTime":"2019-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
"subject":"User Token Meeting",
"isBroadcast": true,
"broadcastSettings": {
"allowedAudience": "everyone",
"isRecordingEnabled": true,
"isAttendeeReportEnabled": true
}
}
```

Getting response

```
    {
"error": {
"code": "MethodNotAllowed",
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-05-07T10:24:58",
"request-id": "17e3655e-158d-44c2-bb92-3a6b2ff3951d",
"client-request-id": "17e3655e-158d-44c2-bb92-3a6b2ff3951d"
}
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

broadcastSettings were not available for V1.0 so, try using with beta version. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta) for more info.